# Instagram Rate Limit

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Are the endpoint-specific rate limits per access token, or for app period. Lets say I have 100 users of the app, (100 different access tokens) that make a relationship post request, is that not going to work? Or is it 60 requests max per user of the app, and no more than 5000 total requests from the app every hour..

Answer (score 3):

Each user can make total of 5000/hr API calls, POST API calls have different limits like relationship POST call has 60/hr. There is no limit for the app, each access_token (user) has a limit.

**Update**: As jhm pointed out, this limit has been reduced from 5000/hr to 200/hr as of April 1, 2018.

Comment: oh my! thank you so much! it kept referring to "your OAuth client", and not "authenticated user" or "access token" so it was confusing. THank you!!

Comment: so wait- just to clarify, you are saying that if i had 5 authenticated users, the app could make a maximum 25000 requests, (5000 from each user) ?

Comment: Yes, but note that POST API calls have a different limits per user, so u cannot make 5000 POST API calls (liking/commenting), but u can make 5000 GET calls per user.

Answer (score 1):

As per the April 1st 2018, the rate limit has been significantly reduced - from 5000 to 200 pr hour pr user:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview/#rate-limiting

Comment: What makes you say that `Developers should be ware that this might be decreased even further in a near future.`?

Comment: Do you have any evidence or reason to believe that it would be decreased further?

Comment: No, you're right - it was an unnecessary comment based on presumption and not fact. It's been removed.