# Instagram API working on local computer but not on server

Tags: python, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I use Instagram API to fetch data in Python. Everything was working fine on my server but now it has started to show error ( json.decoder.JSONDecodeError : ExpectingValue ). I examined the same code on my local machine and found that everything works normal. I even tried the old backup or even changing my server IP but still getting the same error.Later, I checked on server console and found that it's returning 500 error on post request. What could be possibly wrong. ?
Here's one test link : https://www.instagram.com/p/B_qQ8RvlbwH/?__a=1

Comment: Hi, Abhishek you might want to read up on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291101/instagram-rate-limit & https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview/#rate-limiting

Comment: Don't think rate limiting is a problem here